# Accessing function's parent environment and removing objects

Tags: r, function, scoping, rprofile

Let's say that I want to write a simple *rename* function that would load through `.Rprofile`. The function is simple and can be compared to:

```
carsNewName <- mtcars; rm(mtcars)
```

## `.Rprofile`

The function available in `.Rprofile` would be of format:

```
.env$rename <- function(oldName, newName) {
    newName <- oldName
    rm(oldName, envir = parent.env())
    return(newName)
}
```

where the .`env` is attached through `attach(.env)`.

### Question

*How can I access function's parent environment through `parent.env()`?* I.e. if **`rename`** function is called inside another function, I would like to rename objects there not in a global environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f` displays `x` from the parent environment and then displays `x` from the parent frame:

```
f <- function() {

  e <- environment() # current environment
  p <- parent.env(e)
  print(p$x)

  pf <- parent.frame()
  print(pf$x)

}

g <- function() {
  x <- 1
  f()
}

x <- 0
g()
```

giving:

```
[1] 0
[1] 1
```